# Voltage divider for 14.4 V automotive signal - how can I achieve the same 5 V protection without a 5 V reference?

Tags: arduino, voltage, divider

The atShiftSwitch signal is 12-14.4 V. I am looking to step this down to 5 V to use as an Arduino input atShiftSwitchSignal

What I don't understand is what actually happens in this schematic if the atShiftSwitchSignal voltage exceeds 5 V? If I don't have a dedicated 5 V reference am I better off using a 5 V Zener diode?

[image: schematic]

Comment: A 4.7 or 5.1 V Zener diode to ground?

Comment: *What I don't understand is what actually happens in this schematic if the atShiftSwitchSignal voltage exceeds 5 V?* <--Why should it exceed 5 volts?

Comment: If this is a one-off project, 14.4 V is a safe bet. If this is intended to be a commercial product, please be aware that you may need it rated for 80 V load dump condition. Your 47k resistor will do a marvelous job there.